# Requirehttps for DEVELOPMENT and LIVE websites

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ssl, requirehttps

I have some ASP .NET MVC4 website which I have to put first to DEVELOPMENT place to test. And development website doesn't have SSL  but the LIVE has it.

Well. I have to use `[Requirehttps]` inside of 20 controllers and I cannot comment it every time when I have test it under DEV website.

Is there any approach to configure  [Requirehttps] based at least on some web.config settings or perhaps there is another approach? I mean I don't like to comment around 20 `[Requirehttps]` each time when I have publish website under LIVE.

Any clue?

Comment: This is not an answer to your initial question, but why don´t you enable https on your development server?

Comment: @OakNinja Well My parnet said that he cannot apply GoDaddy Sertificate to DEVELOPMENT website...

Comment: You can set up a self-signed certificate for your dev. machine. See: http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-in-iis-7.html and section: Generate a Self Signed Certificate with the Correct Common Name

Comment: I recommend using SSL in your development environment as well since sites behave differently using ssl, like references to javascript files and ajax calls.

Comment: @OakNinja When using IIS Express in VS 2010/2012, all it takes to enable SSL locally on your development machine is setting `Enable SSL` to True on your project properties. See [Working with SSL at Development Time is easier with IISExpress](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx) on Scott Hanselman's blog for further details.

Comment: @Daniel Liuzzi yeah, if you dont work in a team. However,  i guess most teams have a shared development environment running regular IIS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Override the RequireHttpsAttribute

web.config

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="SSL" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

MyHttpsAttribute.cs

```
public class MyHttpsAttribute : RequireHttpsAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (bool.Parse(AppSettings["SSL"]) != true) {
            return;
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
}
```

BaseController

```
[MyHttps]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you switch between debug/release builds, you can do this in your code:

```
#if !DEBUG
    [RequireHttps]
#endif
```